# Can't get days between 2 date

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

Hi I'm new in vfp programming

I have script like this

```
date1 = this.value
date2 = thisform.pgfpagerefresh1.page2.txtpdbound8.value
```

I think it's already in datetime format
 because I can't `wait wind` either date1 or date2 without `wait wind dtoc(date1)`

but somehow I can't get days between two var date above

```
countDays = date11 - date2                      -> fail
countDays = ROUND((date1-date2)/(3600*24),0)    -> fail
```

I already try to convert to string with

```
date1 = TRANSFORM(DTOS(this.value),"@R 9999-99-99")
date2 = TRANSFORM(DTOS(thisform.pgfpagerefresh1.page2.txtpdbound8.value),"@R 9999-99-99")
```

then using ctod to make it back to date format but nothing work

I try to use static variable manually like this and success get number days

```
countDays = date(2016,10,18) - date(2016,10,12)
```

how to convert my var `date1` & `date2` like above

---

**@upddate**

countDays = date1 - date2  `107/operator/operand type mismatch`

Comment: Can you find out what types they actually are first of all:

vartype(this.value)
vartype(thisform.pgfpagerefresh1.page2.txtpdbound8.value)

... and we'll go from there.

Comment: Your values seem to be dates, but you don't explain what does "fail" means. Is the result wrong? Do you see an error message?

Comment: @AlanB is right -- you should know what types they are.  This is your program and you need to know the types of all the variables before you can do work on them.   I don't agree with the idea of using Cast(Cast just because you don't know the variable type.  Also -- use the debugger - it will help you figure things out.

Comment: @AlanB hmm in properties textbox i see it's field `format` with value `K` and dateformat property 0-default

Comment: @CetinBasoz yeah i see error message operand type mismatch. . . please see my update post

Comment: @Missy hm actually this is not my coding....i'm just continue this project from previous worker, and yeah i'm still learning how to use debugger

Comment: @Missy, obviously his version is not VFP9 and doesn't have cast() keyword. Otherwise, would you explain why you disagree using cast(). If he had a chance to use it, then would be a nice way to use like generics in .Net. In a function for example, where the 'date' might be passed as date, datetime or string how would you code it? That function would only know that the parameters is some sort of date representation. You might code tons of ifs to check it is a datetime, date or char. N ways to skin a cat in Fox.

Comment: Maybe his version is VFP9 but typing code wrong.

Comment: Check the value property (and controlsource). What do they show?

Comment: @Neversaysblack -- Cast is a useful function when you want to force your variable type.  It is not useful to have no clue what your variable type is to begin with when you are a beginning programmer.

Comment: Does your code really have both date1 and date11, or is that a typo?

Comment: Cast() has its uses, however a sticking plaster for an underlying problem of typing isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

This would work, whether the values are date, datetime or a string value convertible to a date or datetime:

```
date1 = this.value
date2 = thisform.pgfpagerefresh1.page2.txtpdbound8.value

Local dDate1, dDate2, nDays
dDate1 = Cast(Cast(m.date1 as datetime) as date)
dDate2 = Cast(Cast(m.date2 as datetime) as date)

nDays = Abs(m.dDate2-m.dDate1)

? m.nDays
```

Note: If it is a string than convertibility depends on current date format. ie: if set date dmy then "31/1/2016" would be converted but not "1/31/2016".

Comment: when i try to save this script. . . . i get error when cast date1 -> `function name is missing `

Comment: Would you show us your exact code, what version of VFP that you are using? Exact error line and text you got? You are not describing problem well :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use TTOD() to convert a DateTime to a Date, and then simple subtraction will work for you.

```
d1 = DATETIME(2016, 8, 18, 14, 0, 0)
d2 = DATETIME(2016, 8, 15, 10, 30, 0)

? TTOD(d1) - TTOD(d2)
```

3

Comment: i try to convert that date1 & date2 with `dtoc` then `wait wind` and get format `08/08/2016`....then i try to using `? GetWordNum(date1,1,"/") to substraction string to array. . .but when i'm running . . . .it's dispaly error `1/file 'getwordnum.prg' does not exist. . . .i try with `alines` too but same not working

Comment: I'm not sure why GETWORDNUM() isn't working for you, maybe you've mis-spelled it?  If your variable is of type Date or DateTime, you can use the DAY(), MONTH() and YEAR() functions to extract parts of them.

Comment: Or maybe you're using an early version of VFP that doesn't have support GETWORDNUM().